# can we used soql query in triggers

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I just want to ask you all of you.
can we use soql query in triggers?
when I was searching in google and found that in one article "SOSL is not used in Triggers". while soql is used in triggers.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

The best place to start and learn about SOQL, SOSL and Triggers is [Apex Basics & Database at trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database).

SOQL can be used in Triggers but SOSL is not. The idea to allow it has been raised away long back. You can upvote it:- [Allow SOSL queries in Triggers](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000IIpq)

> SOSL queries are only supported in Apex classes and anonymous
>   blocks. You cannot use a SOSL query in a trigger.

You can get more information here:- [Introduction to SOQL and SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_sosl_intro.htm)

Answer (score -1):

As before release of Spring 11 SOSL are not supported in triggers.
But as per Spring 11 updates we are able to use SOSL in triggers.

Comment: It does appear that we can use SOSL in triggers. Setting aside the difficulty of finding old release notes,  there doesn't seem to be any mention of this in the spring '11 release notes [that I was able to find](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fna1.salesforce.com%2Fhelp%2Fdoc%2Fen%2Fsalesforce_spring11_release_notes.pdf). You should [edit] your answer to include some supporting evidence to corroborate your claim (links to a reputable source, the salesforce dev forums are not a reliable source, or a sample trigger that someone can add to their org to verify this themselves).